# Looping Animation of text color change in multiple elements (text) using CSS3

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I was trying to make a multiple texts changing color animation, like this https://vercel.com. I've nailed down how to make one text change color through keyframes but I can't get them to each text change color on a certain pattern.

For instance [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DArRW.png), you have the word **Develop** in color red, then it should turn to black and change to the word **Preview** on blue, and then this would turn to black and the word **Ship** should turn yellow. And finally this should iterate infinitely.

Here I leave the current code in case it helps:

```css
.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10rem;
  }
  
  .awesome {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #313131;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: flex;
    -webkit-animation: color-change-red 10s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: color-change-red 10s infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: color-change-red 10s infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: color-change-red 10s infinite alternate;
    animation: color-change-red 10s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color-change-red {
    0% { color: red; }
    33.3% { color: black; }
    100% { color: black; }
}
@-moz-keyframes color-change-red {
    0% { color: red; }
    33.3% { color: black; }
    100% { color: black; }
}
@-ms-keyframes color-change-red {
    0% { color: red; }
    33.3% { color: black; }
    100% { color: black; }
}
@-o-keyframes color-change-red {
    0% { color: red; }
    33.3% { color: black; }
    100% { color: black; }
}
@keyframes color-change-red {
    0% { color: red; }
    33.3% { color: black; }
    100% { color: black; }

}

.awesome2 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #313131;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: flex;
    -webkit-animation: color-change-blue 10s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: color-change-blue 10s infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: color-change-blue 10s infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: color-change-blue 10s infinite alternate;
    animation: color-change-blue 10s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color-change-blue {
    0% { color: black; }
    33.3% { color: blue; }
    66.6% { color: black; }
}
@-moz-keyframes color-change-blue {
    0% { color: black; }
    33.3% { color: blue; }
    66.6% { color: black; }
}
@-ms-keyframes color-change-blue {
    0% { color: black; }
    33.3% { color: blue; }
    66.6% { color: black; }
}
@-o-keyframes color-change-blue {
    0% { color: black; }
    33.3% { color: blue; }
    66.6% { color: black; }
}
@keyframes color-change-blue {
    0% { color: black; }
    33.3% { color: blue; }
    66.6% { color: black; }
}

.awesome3 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #313131;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: flex;
    -webkit-animation: color-change-yellow 10s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: color-change-yellow 10s infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: color-change-yellow 10s infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: color-change-yellow 10s infinite alternate;
    animation: color-change-yellow 10s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color-change-yellow {
    0% { color: black; }
    66.6% { color: yellow; }
    100% { color: black; }
}
@-moz-keyframes color-change-yellow {
    0% { color: black; }
    66.6% { color: yellow; }
    100% { color: black; }
}
@-ms-keyframes color-change-yellow {
    0% { color: black; }
    66.6% { color: yellow; }
    100% { color: black; }
}
@-o-keyframes color-change-yellow {
    0% { color: black; }
    66.6% { color: yellow; }
    100% { color: black; }
}
@keyframes color-change-yellow {
    0% { color: black; }
    66.6% { color: yellow; }
    100% { color: black; }
}
```

```html
    <div class='center'>
        <p class="awesome">Develop</p>
        <p class="awesome2">Preview</p>
        <p class="awesome3">Ship</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: You got a lot going on here. Have you inspected the code from the site you're trying to resemble? I would suggest using a `text-stroke` and using a `linear-gradient` background.

Comment: Thanks, but the gradient is not the issue, the multiple text animations working together is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One observation is that in the example site you link to it appears that the colored words stay colored for a bit rather than immediately start to merge with black.

This snippet holds them colored for 30% of the animation, then quite swiftly takes them down to black at a third of the way through the animation.

The other observation is that there is a lot of repeated code here which can make it difficult to see what is going on.

This snippet gives each word the same animation but delays the second one by a third of the total animation time and the third one by two thirds.

It also uses a CSS variable for the color so the same keyframes code can be used for each word.

For clarity it also strips out the browser-specific settings - of course put them back in if required in your use case.

```css
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10rem;
}

.awesome {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #313131;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: flex;
  --duration: 10s;
  animation: color-change var(--duration) infinite;
}

.awesome:nth-child(1) {
  --color: red;
}

.awesome:nth-child(2) {
  --color: blue;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--duration) / 3)
}

.awesome:nth-child(3) {
  --color: yellow;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--duration) * 2 / 3);
}

@keyframes color-change {
  0% {
    color: var(--color);
  }
  30% {
    color: var(--color);
  }
  33.3333% {
    color: black;
  }
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='center'>
  <p class="awesome">Develop</p>
  <p class="awesome">Preview</p>
  <p class="awesome">Ship</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I was able to add gradients through background-image: linear-gradient(), just in case someone is having issues with that.